# Create a custom wordpress menu shows a list of posts as sub menu based on its parent menu items (categories) and display using a shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, navigation, shortcode

I have a custom post-types called products that contain a list of products.

I have created a menu called hierarchical menu in wordpress dashboard > appearance > menus as illustrated below:

```
Electronics
  -> Camera
  -> Headphones
  -> Tv accessories
Computers
  -> Monitors
  -> Keyboards
  -> Mouse
Stationaries
  -> Pen
  -> Pencil
  -> Notebooks
-> Paper
```

I need to create and display a **custom menu** using shortcode for eg., If I click on camera it **displays a list of posts from Product post type with categories** of electronics, camera as a **submenu**

```
Electronics
-> Camera
  --> list of posts with categoreis Electronics / Camera (dynamic)
```

Here is an example of the feature
[image]
Where the fourth column is essentially a list of products with categories highlighted.

See the feature in action
https://www.trelleborg-tires.com/en

I am not sure how to go about creating this. I use below code to generate the menu and display using shortcode. But I have zero clue on how to dynamically show the list of posts based on its parent criteria. Any help / Guidance greatly appreciated would be greatly appreciated.

```
function custom_hierarchical_menu() {
    // Get the generated menu HTML without echoing it
    $menu_html = wp_nav_menu( array(
        'menu'   => 'Hierarchy Desktop Menu',
        'echo'   => false, // Set 'echo' to false to store the HTML in $menu_html
    ) );
    
    return $menu_html;
}

add_shortcode( 'customHierarchicalMenu', 'custom_hierarchical_menu');
```

Comment: _"I have created a menu [...] as illustrated below:"_ - and those links are pointing _where_?

Comment: _"I need to create and display a custom menu using shortcode for eg., If I click on camera it displays a list of posts from Product post type with categories of electronics, camera as a submenu"_ - do you mean, you want to list those products as additional items _in_ the menu? Or do you perhaps rather mean, you want to linkt to a _page_, that then _shows_ those products as part of its content?

Comment: It really rather sounds as if you were trying to re-build already existing functionality yourself. WordPress already has category archive pages, and what those do, is - show the posts (in this case, products) that are _in_ those categories.

Comment: essentially I want to list the products (with camera as category for eg.) as sub menu  not the archive page... I have edited the question to include the example site with the said feature for more clarity

Comment: One way would be to use the `wp_nav_menu_items` hook, to dynamically add the "missing" items into the data structure, that WP_Nav_Walker then uses to generate the HTML output. The other would be to create your own class that inherits from WP_Nav_Walker, and modify the output generation, so that it will make a database query to fetch the relevant products for each "leaf" and then append the HTML structure for that submenu, into the generated HTML for that leaf menu point.